# error: redefinition of typedef in c

Tags: c, struct

We have an assignment in school where we got a header file and we
need to implement it. The header defines:

```
typedef struct Board* BoardP;
```

which to my understanding means the BoardP is a pointer to struct Board.
Anyhow, my implementation is:

```
typedef struct Board
{
    int width;
    int height;
    char *board;
} *BoardP;
```

But i keep getting:

```
Board.c:21: error: redefinition of typedef ‘BoardP’
Board.h:4: note: previous declaration of ‘BoardP’ was here
```

Any ideas as to why this happens? Thanks!

EDIT: another question. As you can see my struct hold an array of characters. When I write a constructor should I initialize (malloc(sizeof(height*width)) the array first and then the struct? And how about use of free()? Should I free the array first and then the struct?
Thanks

Comment: As a side note, I think it's a bad idea to `typedef` pointers. I'd much rather just see `typedef struct Board Board;` and then use `Board *`. a) If it's a poiner, the user should know it's a pointer, so that they're more likely to remember that it probably needs cleaning up when they're done with it. b) If you need a pointer to `const`, simply using `const Board *` is much clearer than `BoardCP`. Whatever naming scheme you come up with for `typedef`s to `const` pointers won't be as clear (and consistent) as the scheme already laid out by the language. (What if you need `volatile` one day?)

Comment: You're right, but school staff wrote the header file and I can't change it. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drop the `typedef` from the definition.

```
struct Board
{
    int width;
    int height;
    char *board;
};
```

A struct is a struct; it's not like you always have to `typedef` it. To be honest, I only `typedef structs` for [opaque pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer).

From [`style(9)`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=style):

> Avoid using typedefs for structure types. Typedefs are problematic
>   because they do not properly hide their underlying type; for example
>   you need to know if the typedef is the structure itself or a pointer
>   to the structure. In addition **they must be declared exactly once**,
>   whereas an incomplete structure type can be mentioned as many times as
>   necessary.

Comment: I also avoid `typedef`ing pointers. `typedef struct thing thing;` is nice, because it avoids the `struct` keyword everywhere and gives you flexibility with `thing *` and `const thing *`.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because in your pre-written header file you have to write an implementation for, you *already* typedef the data type `struct Board *` into a "new" data type `BoardP`. Your explanation that the `BoardP` is the pointer to the data type `struct Board` is correct.

But, to make the code in the header work, you only have to define what's missing, which is, in this instance, only an implementation of the `struct Board` data type.

Your proposed solution would work if you didn't already have the typedef in the header file.

As you already have it in the header file, only the code proposed by cnicutar (the code without the `typedef`) should be put in the *.c* file.

Answer (score -1):

Regarding your second question...

You can `malloc` in either order you like, but I generally allocate the object itself before I try to allocate any sub objects, because that way you have a clear place to store the results of subobject `malloc`s (in the struct) rather than having to store them in otherwise useless temporary variables.

Be sure to handle your errors correctly - if the second `malloc` fails, you'll need to `free` the first one. This is actually a place that many C programmers like to use `goto`:

```
struct Board *makeBoard(...)
{
    struct Board *b = malloc(sizeof *b);
    if(b == NULL) goto end1;

    b->board = malloc(...);
    if(b->board == NULL) goto end2;

    // ...

  end2:
    free(b);
  end1:
    return NULL;
}
```

When you `free` the data, you have to `free` the subobjects before you free the main objects, unless you store pointers to all the subobjects in temporary variables before you `free` the main object. That is, the following won't work:

```
free(b);
free(b->board);
```

Because by the second statement, `b` is `free`d and won't be able to be safely dereferenced. It's cleanest just to do it in the opposite order.

Comment: Why the downvote? Did someone see `goto` and just have a knee-jerk reaction?